# Generating errors when handling omitted values (int) in JSON Binding

Tags: go, go-gin

Using gin-gonic, I'd like to identify when an integer value is omitted from the incoming JSON request even though zero is a possible value. In other words, zero is a valid value but we can't assume a default. Building the struct with pointers seems contrary because there is no valid object with the value not-present. During the marshaling process, I'd like to know if any fields are not populated.

I'm using OpenAPI to define the interface with "required" fields, and I want error responses to match the API definition. I'm using a code generator to create the web models being populated. I'd like to avoid marshaling the JSON into a map, validating the map, and then populating the model.

For example:

```
type mouth struct {
   teeth int
   fillings int
}
```

```
func ProcessTi0(c *gin.Context) {
    var b mouth
    err = c.Bind(&b)
    if err != nil {
      c.JSON(400, gin.H{
          "err": err,
      })
    }
    ....
}
```

Currently a request of `{}` is valid.

The default binding behavior is to silently write a zero into the field if it's not provided, but I'd like to generate an error.

Comment: _Building the struct with pointers seems contrary because there is no valid object with the value not-present._ Did you mean there is a difference between `nil` and not contain field in json? I don't think then it's possible without a map or manually parse the data.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your code generator need support generate custom tags for your model. Then you can refer to https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation, which indicate there has a 'binding' tag you can use to declare which field is required.